# How to catch DB constraint violation and throw UserFriendlyException?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I have a `CrudAppService` defined this way:

```
public class MyAppService : AsyncCrudAppService<MyEntity, MyDto, int, PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto, MyCreateDto, MyDto>, IMyAppService, ITransientDependency
{
    private readonly IRepository<MyEntity> _MyRepository;

    public MyAppService(IRepository<MyEntity> repository) : base(repository)
    {
        _MyRepository = repository;
    }
}
```

I also defined a unique constraint on a field of the entity `MyEntity` so when I try to create more than one entity having the same value for a field, it breaks and throws a `DbUpdateException`. Nice.

Now I would like to catch this exception and rethrow a `UserFriendlyException` to show a message for the user. I tried catching it in an override of the `Create()` method but it does not get catched.

```
public override Task<MyDto> Create(MyCreateDto input)
{
    try
    {
        return base.Create(input);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // Never gets here
        throw new UserFriendlyException("A message for the user");
    }
}
```

So, I tried implementing `IEventHandler<AbpHandledExceptionData>` to filter the `DbUpdateException` and throw the `UserFriendlyException`:

```
class MyExceptionHandler : IEventHandler<AbpHandledExceptionData>, ITransientDependency
{
    public MyExceptionHandler()
    {
    }

    public void HandleEvent(AbpHandledExceptionData eventData)
    {
        if (eventData.Exception is DbUpdateException dbUpdateEx) {
            throw new UserFriendlyException("A message for the user");
        }
    }
}
```

Debugging, I can see that it reaches the `throw new UserFriendlyException` line, but nothing happens (no message is shown to the user), so it seems that the `throw new UserFriendlyException` line is hidden/ignored.

What can I do to solve this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I tried catching it in an override of the `Create()` method but it does not get catched.

You need to call `_unitOfWorkManager.Current.SaveChanges()`:

```cs
public override Task<MyDto> Create(MyCreateDto input)
{
    try
    {
        var dto = base.Create(input);
        _unitOfWorkManager.Current.SaveChanges();
        return dto;
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException ex)
    {
        throw new UserFriendlyException("A message for the user");
    }
}
```

Alternatively, override `SaveChanges` and `SaveChangesAsync` in your DbContext:

```cs
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    try
    {
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException ex)
    {
        throw new UserFriendlyException("A message for the user");
    }
}

public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    try
    {
        return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException ex)
    {
        throw new UserFriendlyException("A message for the user");
    }
}
```

Comment: I implemented the alternative in the `DbContext` and works like a charm. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1):

Are you using ASP.NET Core ?

Because in ABP documentation : (https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Handling-Exceptions)
This document is for the ASP.NET MVC and Web API. If you're interested in ASP.NET Core, see the ASP.NET Core documentation.

I have to use TempData and ViewBag to display error to user in modal...

Comment: Hi @seb49. I'm using APSnet boilerplate with .NET core + Angular so my client app is not written with .NET technologies.